# CALayers Implicit Animation (Rotation)?

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, calayer, rotation

Is it possible to use implicit animation with core animation layers? If so, how would you do so? If you can't what would be the workaround?

I also want the layer to rotate.  Sorry this post is kind of sort, but it's a fairly simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CATransform3DMakeRotation (CGFloat angle, CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat z) to get a CATransform3D object and assign it to self.view.layer.transform . That will immediately rotate the view's layer.